# Android Permissions Aren't Doing Anything

Tags: java, android, sockets, permissions

I've been working with sockets and server sockets with a simple android app, but I've run into problems with the permissions system. I found lots of questions dealing with the same issue, but all those solutions don't seem to do anything.

The symptoms of the issue are:

- When I test the app on my device (not emulator), I get an issue, and it says the app must close.
- The LogCat complains of "FATAL ERRORS", resulting from the construction of the socket.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                try {
                        Socket s = new Socket("[target URL]", 80);
                        s.close();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
        }

}
```

Comment: "I've run into problems with the permissions system" -- what are those problems? "I found lots of questions dealing with the same issue" -- what is the issue? And where are your links to the "lots of questions"?

Comment: Can you please format and post the code here and not redirect  us?

Comment: There was a fair amount of code, so I thought it would be less of an eye sore, but I can put it into the body of the post.

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the exception from LogCat.

Comment: Just the parts which are causing errors is fine

Comment: Post a chunk of code, explain what it does, then post the next check and explain what it is, etc.  Post only relevant parts.  Post the stack trace and if it points to any specific line, tell use that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten about permissions over there. [`<uses-permission>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) needs to be there to access restricted data and hardware of the phone. For your case, you must use following permissions:
1. ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
2. INTERNET

Comment: There's no detectable change with that change implemented. I put the two `uses-permission` elements inside `manifest`, but before (and outside) `application`. Is all that correct?

Comment: Yup, that's correct. Could you post stacktrace? May be I have hit the problem..

Comment: Try adding CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE as well to your permissions.

Comment: Here's the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/LiZhVEHk

Comment: I tried adding CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, but that didn't seem to do much.

Comment: Ah.., problem is so simple, how could I overlook it... You can not have access network on main thread. Create a new thread which would run your socket code asynchronously.